# Visual Studio 2010 intellisense for KnockoutJS inside RequireJS

Tags: knockout.js, requirejs, intellisense

I want to get intellisense, inside Visual Studio 2010, for knockoutJS.

What I have after some research is:

```
///reference path="../lib/knockout/knockout-2.3.0.debug.js" />  
ko.WeGotIntellisenseHere; //As long as we don't add RequireJs intellisense reference above knockout reference

define(['jquery', 'knockout'], function($, ko){
    ///<param name="ko" type="knockout">
    ///some comments
    ///</param>
        ko.NoIntellisenseHere(); // unless I change "type=knockout" by "type=Array"
});
```

Do you know if maybe the "type=knockout" is not correct??? When I change to "type=Array", intellisense works both outside (showing knockout members) and inside (showing Array members) of the "define" function

Same thing happens for jQuery

Note: In the example, I'm not writing the opening tag chracter "<" for the "reference" tag because it has problems on SO

Thanks in advance

Comment: Are you looking for true Intellisense that is guiding you on what is available at the current namespace or just to give you a pseudo-intellisense showing everything available within Knockout?

Comment: mmmm... good question... Since I want to avoid global, I want to have access only to what the parameters bring with them. So, you would call it pseudo right??? As I mention it, if I remove the "ko" parameter, I have access to knockout intellisense (what you would call true intellisense???) inside the "define" function, so when I write "ko." the knockout members appear, but I don't want that because that would be a magic object. Only "define" & "require" are allowed to be magic