# Intellisense on RequireJS dependencies

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-2013, knockout.js, requirejs, intellisense

I have intellisense working surprisingly well in VS2013, for example typing 'ko.' will come up with all of the knockout functions, etc. I have access to.

The problem I am running into now is when defining modules using requirejs in this fashion (e.g.):

```
define(['knockout'], function(ko){
    // ...
});
```

I lose all intellisense on the 'ko' object.  I can understand why this is happening (ko is now a parameter scoped to the function rather than the ko defined in the knockout.js file so VS doesn't know what it is), but is there some way to let VS know the type of the ko parameter so I can still retain the same intellisense I have outside of the module definition?

Comment: If you can't get this working, you may want to try Browserify's require. Works for me with no special configuration.

Comment: I found another post that is similar that might be helpful.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22561756/visual-studio-2010-intellisense-for-knockoutjs-inside-requirejs